# The functionality of wait function

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child, wait

> Hi there I am trying to create this process tree but I still confused whether DABC is possible to be printed or not

```c
void main(){
/*
                                     creating this process tree:  
                                                        P1
                                                      /   \
                                                    P2     P3
*/
    if(fork()){
        if(fork()){
            printf("A\n");
            wait(NULL);
            printf("B\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("C\n");
        }

    }
    else{
        printf("D\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `wait()` waits for any single of the child processes to end. So yes, it is possible to end up with "DABC". See fiddle (I added sleep() to help the desired order) - https://onlinegdb.com/Mycj7Kuuh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

[image: Demonstration of DABC]

In fact, all of the following outcomes are possible:

- ACBD
- ACDB
- ADBC
- ADCB
- CABD
- CADB
- CDAB
- **DABC**
- DACB
- DCAB

This can be visualized by stretching/shrinking a combination of light grey boxes.

There's one condition: One of the child processes must end before the statement after the `wait` in P1. This is because `wait` waits for a child — any child — to end.

Note that you can use `waitpid` to wait for a specific process to end.

Comment: Re “One of the child processes must end before the statement after the `wait` in P1.”: `wait` will return before a child process ends if it is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Indeed, `wait` can be interrupted by a signal, but it can't happen in the program in question since no signal handlers were installed. I generally assume that a person that sets up a signal handler knows that this can cause any blocking system call to fail. // Other errors not covered by this answer: `printf` failing and processes getting killed. // I hadn't considered the possibility of buffering, but it doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: The defaults for some signals, such as `SIGCONT` are to discard the signal. Do those interrupt `wait`?

Answer (score 0):

I take the intent of the exercise to be that you should assume that all function calls complete successfully, that all processes involved terminate normally, and that the return of the `wait()` call can be relied upon to indicate the termination of a child process, as opposed to its temporary stoppage via a signal.  Subject to those assumptions and otherwise considering all allowed sequences of execution, you should recognize that the order of the output is governed by these constraints, and these alone:

- "A" and "B" will be printed in that relative order because that's the program order of a single process.
- At least one of "C" and "D" will be printed before "B" because the `wait()` ensures that one of the child processes (each of which prints one of those letters) finishes before "B" is printed.

"DABC" is among the many sequences consistent with those constraints, so yes, in principle, it is a possible output of the program presented.  Whether that is a *likely* output is an altogether different question, whose answer depends on various characteristics of the C implementation and its operating environment.

If you make fewer of the assumptions enumerated above then that only increases the possible outputs, so the order "DABC" being possible does not depend on those assumptions.

Comment: “C” and “D” may both be printed after “B” because `wait` will return if it is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I originally answered in what I take to be the intent and spirit of the exercise.  I have since revised in light of your comment to be more technically comprehensive.